# Output caching in codeigniter displays blank page

Tags: codeigniter, caching

I've read a lot of discussions about this but have no luck.

I have a controller:

```
function get_list() {

$data['promoname'] = $this->Default_model->get_promo($this->input->post('year'));

$this->output->cache(10);

// Render view

$this->layout->render(get_platform().'/promo/promo_view', $data);

}

And in my Default_model:

function get_promo($year = NULL) {

$this->db->cache_on();

//query here

}
```

When the page is loaded for the first time, the data is displayed perfectly. But when I tried to load it again to check if it is cached it displays nothing, a blank white page. Error reporting is enabled.

A file has been created under `application/cache`, meaning there is no permission issue. But the file created contains '1357184142TS--->'.

Tried to remove the $this->db->cache_on(), but the behavior is still the same. What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check your view file to see if any tags are missed or any values getting interrupted in-between.

Comment: I was not able to add comments to the question.

Comment: Hi. Checked my view but it's all good. Tried to remove code that involves caching, it functions as expected. When tried to bring back the code for caching, the page still displays nothing

Answer (score 0):

As documentation https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/caching.html says:

> Because of the way CodeIgniter stores content for output, caching will only work if you are generating display for your controller with a view.

so you have to call:

`$this->load->view(get_platform().'/promo/promo_view', $data)`

instead of

`$this->layout->render(get_platform().'/promo/promo_view', $data);`

Answer (score -1):

I am having a same problem. I haven't properly tested it though. I think the blank page is caused by using `($this->db->last_query())` in the Code with Nested Queries.

Try changing the `$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;` to `false`. It may resolve the problem if other system queries are not running.